# Write to file in UTF-8 encoding in FSDataOutputStream (Hadoop)?

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, mapreduce, cartodb

I am trying to write csv into a file in the reducer function of MapReduce. Here is my code:

```
public class DataSet311Reducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  @Override
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path path = new Path(key.toString().toLowerCase() + ".csv");
    FSDataOutputStream os = fs.create(path);
    os.writeChars("KEY,DATE,AGENCY,DESCRIPTOR,LOCATIONTYPE,INCIDENTZIP,INCIDENTADDRESS,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE\n");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Text value : values) {
      sb.append(value.toString());
      sb.append("|");
      os.writeUTF(value.toString());
      os.writeUTF("\n");
    }
    os.close();
    context.write(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
  }
}
```

I need to store the file in UTF-8 encoding for use with CartoDB. On checking the fileheader it shows me

`unspecified.csv: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

How do I store the content with proper encoding and header contents ?